# How can I make a number randomizer only choose a number 2 times

Tags: java

So how can I generate a bunch of random numbers (i.e 0-10 and generate 5 numbers that are not duplicates of eachother)

Comment: I dont want to use lists though.

Comment: Specify that in the question. And also why not?

Comment: get the idea .then apply to your case

Comment: Do they have to be integers?  How do you expect to avoid duplicates if you don't keep track of previous numbers?

Comment: I dont really understand them very well, im new to java

Comment: Well, this is a good time to learn about them, then.  A list is a pretty fundamental data structure, and you're going to have to learn about them at some point, so why not now?

Comment: They're the simplest way to do what you've asked. Anyway, they're a crucially fundamental data structure (in Java and generally in programming), so you'll have to learn them at some point. No time like the present.

Comment: Try looking [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_set_interface.htm) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) for ideas/tutorials on sets in java. After you've got a handle on sets, go to [this SO question](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) to answer your question.